# Having difficulty in arrangement of the series.

Tags: combinatorics

There are $28$ students who have written an exam. Rank of Sonakshi is $26$th from the bottom. Rank of Ayushi is 15th from the top. Rank of Jaishree is $6$th from the bottom. Rank of Priya is exactly between Jaishree and Ayushi. Rank of Guriya is $7$ places above Ayushi's rank.

I really do not know how to draw the schematic with proper indices. Particulalry it is difficult to place Priya and deal with the calculation henceforth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** $r$th value from bottom = $(n-r+1)$th from top, where $n$ is total number of values.